# In the Magic School Bus, are Ms Frizzle's dresses determined by the Magic School Bus or entirely independent magic?

Tags: the-magic-school-bus

In the Magic School Bus, Ms Frizzle's dresses seem to always match the field trip they are going on that day. So much so that it often changes as they change location.

We also know that the Magic School Bus can provide clothing to its occupants. (This is particularly obvious in the chapter books.)

So are the Friz's magic dresses a function of the Magic School Bus? Or are they entirely independent with their own magic?

Answer (score 1):

*The Magic School Bus* (at the least the older cartoon version) is explicit that what is shown is not to be taken literally.*  Each episode ended with a segment with kids calling in to talk to the producer about how some of the things they showed were unrealistic.

So questions about the presentation style fall into the realm of things that probably have no answers, and were never intended to have answers.  They are the way they are just to make the most entertaining and informative television episode.

*This is like with *Mystery Science Theatre 3000*:  "... just repeat to yourself its just a show; I should really just relax."